# Copy database field value from one table to another

Tags: sybase-asa

I use Sybase ASA7, I have 2 tables in a database.

Both tables contain 2 fields - **ID** and **EventDateTime** with 20 records.

**ID** field = 1 to 20 in both tables.

Table 1 has the **EventDateTime** field filled in against each **ID**, table 2 does not, they are just null values.

How would I loop through and copy each **eventDateTime** field from table 1 to table 2 so the two tables match ?

Not really familiar with SQL, so apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

```
update Table2
set    EventDateTime = Table1.EventDateTime
from   Table2
join   Table1
on     Table2.ID            =  Table1.ID
and    Table2.EventDateTime is NULL
```

Another option, based on your comments that the tables are the same structure and have the same data (except for the NULL EventDateTime columns):

```
delete Table2

insert into Table2 (ID, EventDateTime) select ID, EventDateTime from Table1
```

Though if you have any delete/insert triggers and/or RI constraints on Table2, this may not be advisable (depending on trigger logic) or doable (in the case of PK/FK constraints).

Comment: The first option is exactly what I needed, as simple as that :) Many thanks for your help.